# Solve this integral $\int \frac{dx} {\sin^5{x}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Let us denote

$$I_{m,n} = \int \sin^m{x} \cos^n{x}\ dx$$

where $m,n$ are integers (possibly negative or zeros).

There are some well-known recurrent formulas for $I_{m,n}$

So... as an example I was trying to solve this particular integral

$$\int \frac{dx} {\sin^5{x}}$$

using these recurrent formulas and I finally got this answer
(the computations were not very long, just 1 or 2 A4 sheets):

$$F(x) = \frac{5}{8} \ln {|\tan \frac{x}{2}|} - \frac{5}{24} \cdot \frac{\cos{x}}{\sin^2{x}} - \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{\cos{x}}{\sin^4{x}}$$

But WA is not giving me a simple expression when I differentiate $F(x)$

Is my answer incorrect? How do I check it with some tool other than WA?

Any ideas how to verify?

**EDIT:** Now I fixed the issues in my calculations and I am getting this answer.

$$\frac{3}{8}\ln|\tan(\frac{x}{2})|-\frac{3}{8}\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^{2}(x)}-\frac{1}{4}\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^{4}(x)}$$

But it still does not match with the WA answer...

[WA answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify%20%28%20derivative%20%28%20ln%20%28abs%28tan%28x%2F2%29%29%29%20%2B%20%203%2F8%20cos%28x%29%20%2F%20%28sin%28x%29%29%5E2%20-%201%2F4%20cos%28x%29%20%2F%20%28sin%28x%29%29%5E4%20%29%20%29%20)

Which one is correct here?

Comment: Have you tried asking WA to evaluate $F'(x)-\frac1{\sin^5x}$?

Comment: Personally I would multiply top and bottom by $\sin x$ and change the variable to $\cos x$ and then do partial fractions.

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/258754 for a very similar problem.

Comment: Try to find the derivate of your $F(x)$, and check the result with Wolfram|Alpha...

Comment: @MartinR I solved $I_{-3,0}$ in the process of solving $I_{-5,0}$ I am just trying to validate my answer.

Comment: @Gae.S. Trying but not very successfully. So I am still not sure if my answer is correct.

Comment: [Well, that was easy](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F48+%2810+csc%5E3%28x%29+%2B+8+csc%5E5%28x%29+%2B+2+cot%5E2%28x%29+csc%28x%29+%285+%2B+12+csc%5E2%28x%29%29+%2B+15+csc%28x%2F2%29+sec%28x%2F2%29%29-csc%5E5x). Apparently your answer is wrong.

Comment: @Gae.S. Hm... OK, well, if you're sure... I will check my computations 1-2 more times.

Comment: @peter.petrov: Gae.S. used Wolfram. I thought one of the conditions for your question was not using Wolfram?

Comment: To @peter.petrov: Did you used a recursive formula like this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3819841/744799

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak Yes... I did, I used a similar one.

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak My formula has $(m-n+2)$ in the denominator. Yours has $m+n$. Maybe this formula of mine is incorrect and hence the whole solution is messed up. Are you sure of your formula there?

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak Oh!!! My formula is wrong there indeed. Sorry. Thanks a lot. The denominator in your formula pointed me to my problem. Thanks. I will redo my calculations now using the correct formulas.

Comment: To @peter.petrov: You are welcome.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3474601/686284

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake somewhere. From [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%201%2Fsin%5E5%28x%29%20dx) and after simplifications you should have (what I get):

$$\frac{3}{8}\ln|\tan(\frac{x}{2})|-\frac{3}{8}\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^{2}(x)}-\frac{1}{4}\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^{4}(x)}$$

Let me know!

---

I think the $24\ln|\tan(\frac{x}{2})|$ is clear and we multiplied it by $\frac{1}{64}$ to give the correct term.

Then re-write the remaining terms (from WA) as:

$$\frac{1}{64}\big[-\frac{1}{\sin^{4}(\frac{x}{2})}-\frac{6}{\sin^{2}({\frac{x}{2})}}+\frac{1}{\cos^{4}(\frac{x}{2})}+\frac{6}{\cos^{2}({\frac{x}{2})}}\big]$$
$$=\frac{6}{64}\big[\frac{\sin^{2}(\frac{x}{2})-\cos^{2}(\frac{x}{2})}{\sin^2({\frac{x}{2})\cos^{2}(\frac{x}{2})}}\big]+\frac{1}{64}\big[\frac{\sin^{4}(\frac{x}{2})-\cos^{4}(\frac{x}{2})}{\sin^4({\frac{x}{2})\cos^{4}(\frac{x}{2})}}\big].$$

Then using $\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)=\cos(2x)$ and $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ the first term becomes:

$$\frac{6}{64}\big[\frac{\sin^{2}(\frac{x}{2})-\cos^{2}(\frac{x}{2})}{\sin^2({\frac{x}{2})\cos^{2}(\frac{x}{2})}}\big]=-\frac{3}{32}\big[\frac{\cos(x)}{\frac{\sin^{2}(x)}{4}}\big]=-\frac{3}{8}\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^{2}(x)}.$$

For the other term we have (numerator is of the form $(A^2-B^2)=(A-B)(A+B)$):

$$-\frac{1}{64}\big[\frac{\cos^{2}(\frac{x}{2})-\sin^2({\frac{x}{2})}}{\frac{\sin^{4}(x)}{2^4}}\big]=-\frac{1}{4}\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^{4}(x)}.$$

Comment: Yeah, I just found the mistake with some help from @AntonVrdoljak

Comment: I get the same answer now but WA gives some very complicated expression.

Comment: See my edit please.

Comment: I've added to my answer!

Answer (score 3):

Use $$\frac{1}{\sin^5x}dx=\frac{\sin{x}}{(1-\cos^2x)^3}dx=-\frac{d(\cos{x})}{(1-\cos^2x)^3}$$

Comment: To the downvoter: What did you find wrong here?

Comment: @Ak19 I didn't downvote but this does not answer my question at all. I am asking for verification of answer, this is just throwing some formula and getting upvotes. Not useful, sorry. I will try this approach too but it's another thing I am asking.

Comment: @peter.petrov   Give another example and I'll show, what we can made. Ask your question.

Comment: Well... other folks said my answer is wrong so I will check my calculations again but...  I am still not sure if it's wrong or not :)

Comment: My questions were there: "Is my answer incorrect? How do I check it with some tool other than WA? Any ideas how to verify?" That's all.

Comment: @peter.petrov   I would be just calculate the integral.

Answer (score 1):

You rationalize by the simple change of variable $t:=\cos x$:

$$\int\frac{dt}{(1-t^2)^3}.$$

The partial fraction decomposition is

$$\frac3{16(1+t)}-\frac3{16(1-t)}+\frac3{16(1+t)^2}+\frac3{16(1-t)^2}+\frac1{8(1+t)^3}-\frac1{8(1-t)^3}$$ and causes no difficulty.

> $$\frac3{16}\log(1-\cos^2x)-\frac3{8(1-\cos^2 x)}+\frac{1+\cos^2x}{8(1-\cos^2 x)^2}.$$

Comment: Integrating rational functions is not yet introduced even (at this point of the book) but OK... As I said the idea was to use these recurrences. Anyway. Thanks. I will check my calculations.

Comment: @peter.petrov: the integration of these simple fractions is... simple.

Comment: OK... well.. good, thanks

Comment: This was the way I also initially thought of, noice. ${(+1)}$

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram Alpha agrees with you. You just typed in the coefficients wrong when specifying the putative antiderivative you wanted differentiated. It took me [some experimenting with brackets](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+%28+derivative+%28+%283%29%2F8+ln+%28abs%28tan%28x%2F2%29%29%29+%2B++%28-3%29%2F8+cos%28x%29+%2F+%28sin%28x%29%29%5E2+-+1%2F4+cos%28x%29+%2F+%28sin%28x%29%29%5E4+%29+%29+) to get it to understand the corrected query.

Comment: Phew... OK, indeed. That is a relief, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest another method: reduction formula for the cosecant (you know that $1$ over sine is the cosecant function):

$$\int \csc^m(x)\ \text{d}x = -\dfrac{\cos(x)\csc^{m-1}(x)}{m-1} + \frac{m-2}{m-1}\int \csc^{m-2}(x)\ \text{d}x$$

Use it twice.

During the process you will have to integrate the cosecant itself, which is a well known integral:

$$\int \csc(x)\ \text{d}x = -\ln(\cot(x) + \csc(x))$$

And eventually the result is:

$$-\frac{1}{64} \csc ^4\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-\frac{3}{32} \csc ^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{64} \sec ^4\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+\frac{3}{32} \sec ^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+\frac{3}{8} \log \left(\sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)-\frac{3}{8} \log \left(\cos \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)$$